# In the future, can questions and answers support the <iframe> HTML tag?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Stack Exchange supports a little bit of HTML.

For example, we can use `<kbd>` tags

```
<kbd>Example</kbd>
```

<kbd>Example</kbd>    <kbd>Example</kbd>

<kbd>**CAT FACE**</kbd>  
  <kbd>**:3**</kbd>

I was wondering if the English Language Learners Stack Exchange would consider supporting the `<iframe>` html tag so that Google Ngrams can be shown.

```
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=gotten+to+know%2Cseen+another+side&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgotten+to+know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen+another+side%3B%2Cc0" width=900 height=500 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

[image: Example of a Google Ngram]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allowing `<iframe>` opens [all kinds of security risks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311227/295232), I don't think Stack Exchange is going to do that.

Note that it *is* possible to link to a generated image; if I replace `interactive_chart` with `chart`, like this:

```
![](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=gotten+to+know%2Cseen+another+side&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgotten+to+know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cseen+another+side%3B%2Cc0)
```

you get this image:

[image]

Comment: I assumed that that the mark down `![](www.website.com/cofee.jpg)` only worked for JPEGs, PNGs, and other traditional image types. I had no idea that I could embed dynamic (procedurally-generated) images such as one of Google's ngrams.

Comment: Am I right that this image is dynamic, and will update as the information on ngrams updates? In other words, is it possible that over time the image here might come to contradict the point made in the answer?

Comment: @gotube Break it a third time, you mean? (See [googlelabs URLs](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Url%3Agooglelabs.com), [blank ngrams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382439/323179)). In case I'm being too subtle, I'll just state outright that I think all images should be uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com to avoid having problems like this.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon actually, that link *is* a PNG image, but it's recognized by your browser by its [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) rather than a file extension. I must admit that I always take screenshots and upload them, because that works for all websites, and include a link to the Ngram page (so that people can verify, and experiment on their own with other queries). This answer was merely to point out what is possible already.

Answer (score 2):

In any case, what HTML is supported is not a decision made on a site-by-site basis, but is made for the whole of Stack Exchange together. Any request to change what HTML is supported would need to be made on the main meta site, and if accepted, implementd by the staff developers. But I agree with Glorfindel that such support is not likely to be implemented. It is common on this site to provide a link to a Google Ngram result, and most users seem to find that acceptable, with no need to embed the result.

Comment: There are exceptions to *how* some bits of HTML are rendered, though. IIRC you can embed YouTube videos in some sites but not others, and of course MathJax is enabled on some other sites but not on yet another different set of sites, so SE *can* make *some* changes on a site-by-site basis.